# IP How to avoid writing out Assignment of Inventions

Tags: intellectual-property

Most (all perhaps) software-related employment contracts want you to list out your prior inventions. I would like not to disclose some of my "inventions" (past projects and such). Wondering how I can do this while at the same time agreeing to some contract. I would like to be protected from them saying I used their technology to create my past invention, while at the same time keeping my invention private from the company.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you could show evidence of your invention (including a verifiable timestamp of some kind, like [this](https://originstamp.org/home)).

Comment: They are asking for a list of inventions, not an assignment. You might want to edit the title.